# .gitconfig - Permission denied - OS X El Capitan

Tags: github, terminal, permissions, osx-elcapitan, git-config

i have problem to edit .gifconfig file on latest OS X.
I use terminal to open:

```
$HOME/.gitconfig
```

But getting:

```
-bash: /Users/User/.gitconfig: Permission denied
```

Any help ideas this?

Comment: You can try `sudo open` or `chmod 777  $HOME/.gitconfig`